# PHP DateTime Error with huge amount of Data

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, innodb, propel

I've got a Problem with DateTime in PHP. In my Testcase I have 10.000 Rows that are pulled from a MySQL InnoDB Database. This works fine, as my local development is running on a SSD and it takes about 10 Seconds to pull all Rows.
As ORM in PHP I'm using Propel. (because I like the Getter and Setter, anyway). The Problem is that after a few rows, approx at the 50 row, the calculation gets more and more off. I'm trying to Display a "due time".

The Code looks like this and it's working, until the 50 row.

```
$dateTime = $message->getReceivedat ();
$dateinterval = new DateInterval("PT15M");
$dateTime->add ($dateinterval);
echo $dateTime->format ('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

after the 50 row, it gets more and more off. At the 10.000 i got + 1 Day and 4 hours. So maybe it's a buffer Error from InnoDB, or Propel to not give me the right Dates.

Here are the values i get.

> |ReceivedAt           | DueTo |
>
> 24-07-2015 16:11:24     | 24-07-2015 16:26:24 The first row
> 24-07-2015 16:11:46     | 24-07-2015 16:28:46 The second one (is already of by 2 minutes)
> 29-07-2015 15:11:11    | 29-07-2015 16:14:11 The last row is this one.

I'm developing locally on a Windows 8.1 x64, XAMPP (newest Version), Propel (newest Version), 24GB DDR3 RAM, and Intel I7-4790, and the Database is on a 256gb Samsung SSD.

Comment: Can you show the values you get?

Comment: I've added the values in the question above.

Comment: which calculation? `approx at the 50 row, the calculation gets more and more off.`

Comment: @snickbrack 
$dateTime->add ($dateinterval);
echo $dateTime->format ('d-m-Y H:i:s');
this "calculation" i want to add 15 minutes to the original Date. so that 08:00 will be displayed in the "DueTo" Column as "08:15". But this is totally off. as you can see above.

Comment: then the data from your DB is incorrect

Comment: @Snickbrack thanks! i got it, it was a formatting error with the "echo" in php. I did use H:II:s instead of H:i:s. But it's interesting that the echo showed the wrong time and was off completely. 
How can I mark an answer as correct?

Comment: @PhilippKahr now you can select my answer as correct ;) just click on the green mark besides my answer

Comment: Smells like you are mis-converting DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it, it was a formatting error with the "echo" in php. I did use H:II:s instead of H:i:s. But it's interesting that the echo showed the wrong time and was off completely.

Answer (score 1):

The data which you are retreiving from the database is not correct, but with no more input i cannot explain you what the error is.